# disabling certain services in UIDocumentController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have the following code to post photo to instagram:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* homePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* basePath = @"integration/instagram";
    NSString* tmpFileName = @"jumpto.ig";

    NSString* dirPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", homePath, basePath];
    NSString* docPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", dirPath, tmpFileName];

    //clear it out and make it fresh
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:docPath error:nil];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dirPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil]) {

        NSData* imgData = [self generateImageData:img];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:docPath contents:imgData attributes:nil];
        NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:docPath isDirectory:NO ];

        NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://camera"];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
            //imageToUpload is a file path with .ig file extension
            self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
            self.documentInteractionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
            self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
            self.documentInteractionController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Caption Test" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
            [self.documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

The issue is that when I open the popover, I see other services such as facebook/twitter/mail/print/assign to contact/copy/etc. How do I make it such that I only have one option which is Open in Instagram?

Comment: If you only want to support a specific service (Instagram), then why use `UIDocumentInteractionController`? Provide your own simple UI (alert or action sheet perhaps). If the user says Yes, then you can directly launch Instagram with the proper URL.

Comment: Why can't you just disable the other options?

Comment: Because you can't. There is no API for that. The whole point to `UIDocumentInteractionController` is to show a user all of the possible apps that support the specific file/UTI.

Comment: BTW - are you sure you are not confusing `UIDocumentInteractionController` and `UIActivityViewController`?

Comment: rmaddy, you have to use `UIDocumentInteractionController` to pass image data between apps.  Also, `UIActivityViewConroller` would do nothing here.  Instagram provides an exclusive extension (.igo) to limit other apps from appearing in this exact scenario.

Comment: @Tim Many apps (like one of my own) supports all file types. So having an exclusive extension doesn't help in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Instagram listens to both .jpg/.ig files as well as a special extension called `.igo` (Instagram Only).  By changing the filename to .igo, only instagram should show up in the list:

```
NSString* tmpFileName = @"jumpto.igo";
```

Source: [Instagram iPhone Hooks](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/)

Edit: I think there's a logical issue with how you're writing the file. Instead of using NSFileManager to write out the contents on this line:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:docPath contents:imgData attributes:nil];
```

Try using the NSData object itself to write it into place:

```
[imgData writeToFile:docPath atomically:NO];
```

I'm not certain this will result in a different file, but I'm wondering if the way `NSFileManager` creates files with data is differently than how `NSData` writes the data directly.

Comment: I changed it to .igo and I still see the other services

Comment: Very strange.  How are you generating the image?  `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`?

Comment: I am using   UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

Comment: and then yes calling UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0);

Comment: okay we've got a bit of progress here.. when I changed it to what you said, it now shows just instagram and mail. just need to get rid of the mail one

Comment: Very interesting... Not sure what else to tell you at this point.

Comment: It's interesting that [imgData writeToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:docPath] atomically:NO] actually returns NO. And hence the sharing to instagram doesn't work

Comment: Ohh - you may need to use `writeToFile:atomically:` instead - see updated answer

Comment: Because `writeToURL:`, when passed an invalid URL, will fail to write - this often happens when dealing with local files, where `writeToPath:` is meant specifically for writing local files.

Comment: I actually tried that, and now it's back to square 1 again, where all of the options are showing up